# Terraform Kubernetes on Aws/Azure with common template

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I want to deploy kubernetes structure in azure and aws using terraform. Can I do this with a single file for kubernetes without creating different templates?

- aws_provider.tf
- azure_provider.tf
- kubernetes.tf >> This template can be common template ?

There are separate kubernetes configuration for all service providers.

Comment: Nope, there are different managed services in Azure and AWS, AKS and EKS, respectively. Additionally, each provider has its own APIs to make everything happen. You can however use the `kubernetes` provider afterwards to deploy same K8s elements to both clusters.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what the ask is here because of the non-standard terminology, but yes you can have a single Terraform config to interact with both Kubernetes clusters assuming that you have two declared Kubernetes providers with provider aliases and declare the config as a module twice.